# Thread configuration in spring boot with embedded tomcat

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, tomcat, threadpool

I have spring boot application with embedded tomcat and Java melody configured to it using dependency in pom.xml.

I am doing performance testing for my application but problem is no matter how big load is i.e 30hits per second or 500hits per second. Number of threads in java melody in not going beyond 25-30.

Is their any default configuration in spring boot which is limiting the threads opening or any resources depend like memory or cpu ? I am not using any thread configuration in my application which means by default it will have 200 threads if i am not wrong.
Please suggest.
Note : I am running my application with 5gb memory and 2 vCPU.

Comment: And how are you testing things? Running app and test on same machine? Running on seperate machines? How many connections to the database do you have? Do you have `open=-session-in-view-enabled`?

Comment: I am using Jmeter to create load. Application is running in Kubernetees while testing is running on different VM. I have enabled 15 connection to database.  Session open enabled parameter is not added in my spring application

Comment: If that parameter isn't added it is enabled (by default), which means your handling is more or less limited by the number of connections you allow to your database.

Comment: I don't know much about this, but I'd expect Tomcat will configure the optimal amount of threads automatically.